# What is the current folder for img references of static page

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

When a page is rendered using the `page.setContent` method of some static Html content, what is the current folder for attributes such as the `src` of `img` tags?

For example, for:

```
await page.setContent("<img src="./pic.jpg" />");
```

where is the folder `./`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's `undefined`, here is my test result:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('request', request => console.log('send request: ' + request.url()));
  page.on('console', message => console.log('console: ' + message.text()));
  await page.setContent('<img src="./test.jpg" /><script>console.log("href="+window.location.href);</script>');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

output:

```
console: href=about:blank
```

The page URL is `about:blank` and there's no requests sent.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('request', request => console.log('send request: ' + request.url()));
  page.on('console', message => console.log('console: ' + message.text()));
  await page.setContent('<base href="https://www.google.com"><img src="./test.jpg" /><script>console.log("href="+window.location.href);</script>');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

output:

```
console: href=about:blank
send request: https://www.google.com/test.jpg
console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

browser request `test.jpg` after appending a `base` element while the URL is still `about:blank`

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('request', request => console.log('send request: ' + request.url()));
  page.on('console', message => console.log('console: ' + message.text()));
  // set base href to local URL
  await page.setContent('<base href="file:///abc/index.html"><img src="./test.jpg" /><script>console.log("href="+window.location.href);</script>');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

output:

```
console: href=about:blank
console: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///abc/test.jpg
send request: file:///abc/test.jpg
```

Comment: I am using this in a Node app. Would that make a difference? There's no `window` object.

Comment: I have updated my test result

Answer (score 0):

The folder is located from the page you are visiting.

For example if the URL is

mydomain.com/directory1/page.html

The image can be found at mydomain.com/directory1/pic.jpg

Comment: Hmm... there's no url, thus no domain. The page is rendered from a string of Html text.

Comment: In that case the image must be in the same directory as the page